# Python - returns syntax error on request that should work

Tags: python

I'm making a small program in order to create an effective calculator. The program so far is fine but I ran into this problem while trying to get my variables to be set within a function

```
def request(
  val1 = int(input('Enter the first value: '))
  operation1 = (input('''Enter the operation: '''))
  val2 = int(input('Enter the second value: '))
)
```

For some reason only the third line (operation1) has an error. Unsure if python is being dumb or what I'm doing wrong

Comment: In `(input('''Enter the operation: '''))`, the outer parentheses don't make much sense.

Comment: `def request(...<code>...)` is just plain wrong. Don't put actual code inside a function declaration. Only parameters and default values.

Comment: You need to go back to the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) here, as your syntax is very, very wide of the mark. The `def functionname(..)` syntax expects a comma-separate set of argument names, optionally with default values and annotations. Your code is missing the commas, and I highly doubt you wanted the `input()` calls to provide the default values for the arguments.

Comment: For future reference, please also note that "has an error" and "ran into a problem" aren't particularly good descriptions of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the function syntax in python is:

```
def fxnName(args_if_any):
    val1 = int(input('Enter the first value: '))
    ...
```

You are wrapping all lines within the parameter space for a function..

Answer (score 0):

Python has a very strict function syntax, unlike other programming languages that don't require white space.  Additionally, the syntax you're using isn't correct because you're using "()" to define the outer limits of the function.  The correct version of your function would be:

Note the ':' and then the indentation.  If you remove the indentation, it will not run.  And if you don't use the ':' it will not work.

```
def request():
    val1 = int(input('Enter the first value: '))
    operation1 = (input('''Enter the operation: '''))
    val2 = int(input('Enter the second value: '))
request()
```